# CISCO E2500 firmware alteration

Tags: routes, network-programming, dd-wrt

I got into the firmware programming area very recently and I am in need of your expert advice on keeping my initial step in to this area.

I want to modify the firmware of CISCO E2500 router to enhance the routing of IPv4 and IPv6 which includes altering the routing table in the process.

I have decided to go with dd-wrt firmware to implement my solution. Since I am new to this whole area I don't know if this task is feasible or which firmware file to download from (http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/support/router-database) to perform this task.

First I downloaded `2500 v1 Firmware - Webflash image` from dd-wrt and was in the dark cause I was not sure.

I would greatly appreciate if you kind experts would point me in the right direction in this matter.

Comment: Are you trying to install a firmware update written by someone else, or are you trying to write your own version of the firmware?

Comment: @RowlandShaw thank you for the reply :) I am trying to write my own firmware using dd-wrt opensource firmware as my foundation :) do you have an idea about this matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [DD-WRT forum](http://www.dd-wrt.com/phpBB2/) is definitely a better place to find people who are experienced with doing this and get advice related to rolling your own firmware.

For your specific model, the flashing process is outlined briefly and discussed in [this thread](http://www.dd-wrt.com/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?p=775305).

More detailed steps can be found on the wiki page for your model [here](http://dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Linksys_E2500).

lightsword hosts many versions of Linksys firmware source code on his sourceforge page [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/officiallinksysfirmware/files/).

As I'm sure you are already aware, flashing you firmware always comes with some level of risk. You should carefully review all instructions, warnings, and related discussions before attempting the steps outlined on the pages linked above.

Comment: thank you very much for answering my query .. it was indeed helpful :)